# MsgWaitForMultipleObjects returning Access Denied

Tags: delphi, winapi, wait

I have the follow function that creates a process:

```
function .CreateProcess(aAppletPath: string; var aError : string; aProcessInfo: TProcessInformation): Boolean;
var
  StartInfo: TStartupInfo;
begin
  FillChar(StartInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
  FillChar(aProcessInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  if False then begin
    StartInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    StartInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  end;
  if Windows.CreateProcess(nil, PChar(aAppletPath), nil, nil, False, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP + NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, StartInfo, aProcessInfo) then begin
    Result := True;
    WaitForInputIdle(aProcessInfo.hProcess, oTimeOutSecs * 1000);
  end
  else begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

And I have this method that waits the app terminates:

```
function WaitForProcessTerminate(aHandle: THandle) : Boolean;
var
  vResult : LongWord;
    Msg: TMsg;
  PHandles: Pointer;
begin
  vResult := 0;
  PHandles := @aHandle;
  PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
  while True do begin
    vResult := Windows.MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(1, PHandles^, False, oTimeOutSecs * 1000, QS_ALLINPUT);
    if vResult = WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1 then begin
      if PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then begin
        TranslateMessage(Msg);
        DispatchMessage(Msg);
      end;
    end
    else begin
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  case vResult of
        WAIT_ABANDONED: Result := False;
        WAIT_OBJECT_0: Result := True;
        WAIT_TIMEOUT:   Result := False;
    else begin
        Result := False;
    end;
    end;
  if not Result then begin
    ShowMessage(SystemErrorMessage);
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that the wait function is always returning `WAIT_FAILED` with the `Access denied` message. What am I doing wrong? This code is Delphi 2010 and the app i am calling is a java app.

Comment: Please call `UniqueString(aAppletPath)` before calling `CreateProcess`; the API is allowed to modify the string you pass to it, so you should make sure *your* caller doesn't also get a modified value in return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind guys. It was my mistake. The function:

```
function .CreateProcess(aAppletPath: string; var aError : string; aProcessInfo: TProcessInformation): Boolean;
```

should be:

```
function .CreateProcess(aAppletPath: string; var aError : string; var {should be var!!} aProcessInfo: TProcessInformation): Boolean;
```

My apologies.

Comment: Better yet, use `out` to indicate to callers that they don't need to assign anything before calling your function.